# Optimistic locking blocks on Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere, jpa-2.0, websphere-8

I am having issues with optimistic locking in JPA using WAS 8.0.7.
I have a Web project using EJB 3 + JPA 2 (SQL Server, XA datasource).
I am having two JPA Entities X and Y.

X has a OneToMany relation to Y.

Both entities have a @Version field (and there is a version column in the corresponding SQL tables).

Although it is default, i have set a `<property name="openjpa.LockManager" value="version"/>` in the persistence.xml

I persist entity X inside a method x() of a Stateless EJB using Container Managed Transactions.

Method x() creates and persists an entity X and continues to do some business processing on X until it returns.

Let's say that method x() is called from several web requests.

The first request calls x() and creates a X entity.

Meanwhile If a second request calls method x() it blocks until the first request is completed.

Is this the appropriate behaviour using optimistic locking? Shouldn't the second request continue and throw an OptimisticLockException in case there is a concurrent update?

Instead it just blocks as if using pessimistic locking.

Answer (score 0):

Check your datasource isolation level settings (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frdat_isolevtab.html)

High isolation lever may lock all tables referenced (eg. `select`ed) in a transaction up until it's end.

Comment: I am not sure, but the Access Intent profile is used on CMP beans. Anyway, only if i change the isolation level to `READ_UNCOMMITTED` there is no blocking. The problem is that using Optimistic locking with `READ_COMMITTED` blocks.